# Parse Google GeoCode xml in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, geolocation

Ok so I got my little chunck of code that goes out and brings back xml from google for my location after i send it the lat and long. What I now need to be able to do is just get one line out of it.
From the second result set I need to get formatted_address.
Never done any xml parsing in vb.net so I am way lost.

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=44.46944050638752,-88.08779155546756&sensor=false")
    Return result
```

After that I am lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone needs to know. I figured it out. Here is what i did:

```
Dim myAddress As String = "Nothing"
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=lat,long&sensor=false")

    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(result)
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList

    m_nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")


    myAddress = m_nodelist(1).InnerText

    result = myAddress
```